# Reading text Files - single line vs. multiple lines

Tags: delphi-xe2

I am working on a particular scenario, where I have to read from a Text File, parse it, extract meaningful information from it, perform SQL queries with the information and then produce a reponse, output file.

I have about 3000 lines of code. Everything is working as expected. However I have been thinking of a connendrum that could possibly dissrupt my project.

The text file being read (lets call it Text.txt) may consist of a single line or multiple lines.

In my case, a 'line' is identified by its segment name - say ISA, BHT, HB, NM1, etc... each segment ending is identified by a special character '~'.

Now if the file consists of multiple lines (such that each line corresponds to a single segment); say:-

ISA....... ~

NM1....... ~

DMG....... ~

SE........ ~

and so on.... then my code essentially reads each 'line' (i.e. each segment), one at a time and stores it into a temp buffer using the following command :-

```
         ReadLn(myFile,buffer);
```

and then performs evaluations based on each line. Produces the desired output. No problems.

---

However the issue is... what if the file consists of only a single line (consisting of multiple segments), represented as:-

ISA....... ~NM1....... ~DMG....... ~SE........ ~

then with my ReadLine command I read the entire line instead of each segment, one at a time. This doesn't work for my code.

I was thinking about creating an if, else statement pair...which is based on how many lines my Txt.txt file consists of..such as:-

if line = 1:-
then extract each segment at a time...seperated by the special character '~'
     perform necessary tasks (3000 lines of code)
else if line > 1:-
then extract each line at a time (corresponding to each segment)
     perform necessary tasks (3000 lines of code).

now the 3000 lines of code is repeated twice and I don't find it elegant to copy and paste all of that code twice.

I would appreciate if I could get some feedback on how to possibly solve this issue, such that, regardless of a one-line file or multiple-line file...when i proceed to evaluate, i only use one segment at a time.

Comment: If ISA is the start of the "thingie" in the file, then forget lines, read up to the next ISA (or EOF), and then break up the (ISA)block from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways of doing this.  Which is best for you might depend on how long these files are and how important performance is.

A simple solution is to just read characters one at a time until you hit your tilde delimiter. 
The routine ReadOneItem below shows how this can be done.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  FileName = 'c:\kuiper\test2.txt';
var
  MyFile : textfile;
  Buffer : string;

  // Read one item from text file MyFile.
  // Load characters one at a time.
  // Ignore CR and LF characters
  // Stop reading at end-of-file, or when a '~' is read

  function ReadOneItem : string;
  var
    C : char;
  begin
    Result := '';

    // loop continues until break
    while true do
      begin

        // are we at the end-of-file? If so we're done
        if eof(MyFile) then
          break;

        // read in the next character
        read ( MyFile, C );

        // ignore CR and LF
        if ( C = #13 ) or ( C = #10 ) then
          {do nothing}
        else
          begin

            // add the character to the end
            Result := Result + C;

            // if this is the delimiter then stop reading
            if C = '~' then
              break;
          end;
      end;
  end;


begin
  assignfile ( MyFile, FileName );
  reset ( MyFile );
  try

    while not EOF(MyFile) do
      begin
        Buffer := ReadOneItem;
        Memo1 . Lines . Add ( Buffer );
      end;

  finally
    closefile ( MyFile );
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a file mapping via the Win32 API `CreateFileMapping()` and `MapViewOfFile()` functions, and then just parse the raw data as-is, scanning for `~` characters and ignoring any line breaks you might encounter in between each segment.  For example:

```
var
  hFile: THandle;
  hMapping: THandle;
  pView: Pointer;
  FileSize, I: DWORD;
  pSegmentStart, pSegmentEnd: PAnsiChar;
  sSegment: AnsiString;
begin
  hFile := CreateFile('Path\To\Text.txt', GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);
  if hFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  try
    FileSize := GetFileSize(hFile, nil);
    if FileSize = INVALID_FILE_SIZE then RaiseLastOSError;
    if FileSize > 0 then
    begin
      hMapping := CreateFileMapping(hFile, nil, PAGE_READONLY, 0, FileSize, nil);
      if hMapping = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
      try
        pView := MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, FileSize);
        if pView = nil then RaiseLastOSError;
        try
          pSegmentStart := PAnsiChar(pView);
          pSegmentEnd := pSegmentStart;
          I := 0;
          while I < FileSize do
          begin
            if pSegmentEnd^ = '~' then
            begin
              SetString(sSegment, pSegmentStart, Integer(pSegmentEnd-pSegmentStart));
              // use sSegment as needed...
              pSegmentStart := pSegmentEnd + 1;
              Inc(I);
              while (I < FileSize) and (pSegmentStart^ in [#13, #10]) do
              begin
                Inc(pSegmentStart);
                Inc(I);
              end;
              pSegmentEnd := pSegmentStart;
            end else
            begin
              Inc(pSegmentEnd);
              Inc(I);
            end;
          end;
          if pSegmentEnd > pSegmentStart then
          begin
            SetString(sSegment, pSegmentStart, Integer(pSegmentEnd-pSegmentStart));
            // use sSegment as needed...
          end;
        finally
          UnmapViewOfFile(pView);
        end;
      finally
        CloseHandle(hMapping);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hFile);
  end;
```

Comment: could you explain a bit more? or provide me with example links ?